# Printing Boolean Array in Java

Tags: java

How can i print prime from main function.
My code is given below...

```
public static boolean[] sieve(int n) {
    boolean[] prime = new boolean[n+1];
    Arrays.fill(prime, true);
    prime[0] = false;
    prime[1] = false;
    int m = (int) Math.sqrt(n);

    for (int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
        if (prime[i])
            for (int k=i*i; k<=n; k+=i )
                prime[k] = false;
    }
    return prime;
}
```

Comment: [`Arrays#toString(boolean[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double[]%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not want to print `boolean` array: it's of little use. You need to print the primes from the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), which can be done by enumerating the indexes, checking if `primes[i]` is `true`, and printing the index if it is.

```
boolean primes = sieve(100);
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++) {
    if (primes[i]) {
        // This is where you print i or do whatever else you think is appropriate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this you want?

```
public static void getPrime(int n) {
    boolean[] arr = new boolean[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = isPrime(i);
        System.out.println(i + "," + arr[i]);
    }

}

public static boolean isPrime(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to check from 1 to n number prime or not you can do it as follows

```
public static void getPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "," + isPrime(i));
    }

}

public static String isPrime(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return "Not a prime";
    }
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0)
            return "Not a prime";
    }
    return "prime";
}
```

If you need prime numbers only, you can do it as followa

```
public static void getPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i))
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}

public static boolean isPrime(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No.Is this a good algorithm to calculate prime?

Comment: If you want to find prime numbers from 1 to n, you can use this code. But then you can simplify as follows

      public static void getPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "," + isPrime(i));
        }

    }

    public static String isPrime(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return "Not a prime";
        }
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0)
                return "Not a prime";
        }
        return "prime";
    }